# Melting a cast data frame gives incorrect output

Tags: r, reshape

I've encountered a strange behaviour in `cast`/`melt` from the `reshape` package. If I cast a `data.frame`, and then try to `melt` it, the `melt` comes out wrong. Manually unsetting the "df.melt" class from the cast `data.frame` lets it be melted properly.

Does anyone know if this is intended behaviour, and if so, what is the use case when you'd want it?

A small code example which shows the behaviour:

```
> df <- data.frame(type=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), variable="n", value=c(71, 72, 68, 80, 21, 20))

> df
  type variable value
1    1        n    71
2    1        n    72
3    2        n    68
4    2        n    80
5    3        n    21
6    3        n    20

> df.cast <- cast(df, type~., sum)
> names(df.cast)[2] <- "n"

> df.cast
  type   n
1    1 143
2    2 148
3    3  41

> class(df.cast)
[1] "cast_df"    "data.frame"

> melt(df.cast, id="type", measure="n")
         type value value
X.all.      1   143 (all)
X.all..1    2   148 (all)
X.all..2    3    41 (all)

> class(df.cast) <- "data.frame"
> class(df.cast)
[1] "data.frame"

> melt(df.cast, id="type", measure="n")
  type variable value
1    1        n   143
2    2        n   148
3    3        n    41
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you `melt` a df that's already in long format? And your use of `cast` doesn't make much sense either. Usually you use it *after* you use `melt`.

Comment: Please explain a bit more about what you were trying to do and the result you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an OLD question, and not likely to generate a lot of interest. I also can't quite figure out *why* you're doing what you demonstrate in your example. Nevertheless, to summarize the answer, either:

1. Wrap your `df.cast` in `as.data.frame` before "melting" again.
2. Ditch "reshape" and update to "reshape2". That wasn't applicable when you posted this question, since your question predates version 1 of "reshape2" by about half a year.

Here's a lengthier walktrhough:

First, we'll load "reshape" and "reshape2", perform your "casting", and rename your "n" variable. Obviously, objects appended with "R2" are those from "reshape2", and "R1", from "reshape".

```
library(reshape)
library(reshape2)
df.cast.R2 <- dcast(df, type~., sum)
df.cast.R1 <- cast(df, type~., sum)
names(df.cast.R1)[2] <- "n"
names(df.cast.R2)[2] <- "n"
```

Second, let's just have a quick look at what we've got now:

```
class(df.cast.R1)
# [1] "cast_df"    "data.frame"
class(df.cast.R2) 
[1] "data.frame"
str(df.cast.R1) 
# List of 2
#  $ type: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#  $ n   : num [1:3] 143 148 41
#  - attr(*, "row.names")= int [1:3] 1 2 3
#  - attr(*, "idvars")= chr "type"
#  - attr(*, "rdimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
#   .. ..$ type: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#   ..$ :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
#   .. ..$ value: Factor w/ 1 level "(all)": 1
str(df.cast.R2)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ type: num  1 2 3
#  $ n   : num  143 148 41
```

A few observations are obvious:

- By looking at the output of `class`, you can *guess* that you won't have any problems doing what you're trying to do if you're using "reshape2"
- Whoa. That output of `str(df.cast.R1)` is the strangest looking `data.frame` I've ever seen! It actually looks like there are two single variable `data.frame`s in there.

With this new knowledge, and with the prerequisite that we do not want to change the `class` of your casted `data.frame`, let's proceed:

```
# You don't want this
melt(df.cast.R1, id="type", measure="n") 
#          type value value
# X.all.      1   143 (all)
# X.all..1    2   148 (all)
# X.all..2    3    41 (all)

# You *do* want this
melt(as.data.frame(df.cast.R1), id="type", measure="n")
#   type variable value
# 1    1        n   143
# 2    2        n   148
# 3    3        n    41

# And the class has not bee altered
class(df.cast.R1)
# [1] "cast_df"    "data.frame"

# As predicted, this works too.
melt(df.cast.R2, id="type", measure="n")
#   type variable value
# 1    1        n   143
# 2    2        n   148
# 3    3        n    41
```

---

If you're still working with `cast` from "reshape", consider upgrading to "reshape2", or write a convenience wrapper function around `melt`... perhaps `melt2`?

```
melt2 <- function(data, ...) {
  ifelse(isTRUE("cast_df" %in% class(data)), 
         data <- as.data.frame(data), 
         data <- data)
  melt(data, ...)
}
```

Try it out on `df.cast.R1`:

```
melt2(df.cast.R, id="type", measure="n")
#    ype variable value
# 1    1        n   143
# 2    2        n   148
# 3    3        n    41
```

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, any reason you haven't switched? (Asks a guy who generally sticks with base R reshape for all his reshaping needs.)

Comment: I just have not felt the need, I mainly used `melt` to prep data for ggplot2 or plyr, not much more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to melt the data frame **before** you cast it.  Casting without melting first will yield all kinds of unexpected behavior, because reshape has to guess the structure of your data.